# Jquery -How to do to combined image drag-drop and image zoom?

Tags: jquery

For my jquery web-application I have a gallery of thumbnails on my page and i would like to be able to:

1. Drag drop any image into a target div
2. When single click on any image the image would expand and show the larger version of the image on the screen.

I have tried to do this my self but it fails as when I drag it it also starts to zoom the image. Any ideas on how to do this?

I have tried with http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/image-zoom/ and the Jquery UI library.

What i have done so far is:

```
jQuery(document.body).imageZoom();

$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable();
    $("#droppable").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight').find('p').html('Dropped!');
        }
    });

});
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's strange that the image begins to zoom when you start dragging. I looked at the implementation of the Image Zoom plugin you linked, and it uses the click event (technically, the `onclick` event), which shouldn't be triggered until the mouse is pressed and released within the bounds of the same element.

I just set up a minimal test case of the jQuery UI Draggable plugin to record every time the click event is registered on a draggable element. Sure enough, if you click the mouse and release without dragging, you get a click event. However, as soon as you begin dragging a draggable, the click event will **not** trigger (even when you release it).

So anyway, that's why it's weird that you're seeing the Image Zoom plugin zooming the image while its being dragged. Maybe try a different image zooming plugin? There are several linked at the top of the recently decommissioned [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) page.

Comment: You're right about that clicking. Anyone who wants to test as well: see http://jsbin.com/axosa (which I once created for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536791/what-percentage-of-followed-hyperlinks-might-have-their-onclick-javascript-igno/1537217#1537217)